# Google Maps not showing current location or locate button

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have my google maps view embedded in a TabBar Controller and it is the second item in the tab. The view loads the map but it doesn't display the current location or the locate button. I have already edited the scheme to include a location for the build to use.

```
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var didFindMyLocation = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(33.7,
            longitude: -77.4, zoom: 8.0)
        mapView.camera = camera

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if !didFindMyLocation {
            let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

            didFindMyLocation = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If location permission was previously set `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)` probably isn't being called because the authorization status is not changing.

You can also just manually perform a check for authorization and then enable the location on the map

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
                && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
   mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
}
```

[Checking authorization status documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus)

Comment: How can I get the user location from that point? I implemented what you have above in viewdidload and added: mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(mapView.myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0) in the if statement block but the program crashes because mapView.myLocation.coordinate is nil.

Comment: @wxcoder the map view retrieves the current asynchronously from core location when available so it won't be available immediately.  With what you have in your original example the location will be retrieved to update the camera in observeValueForKeyPath and everything should be fine.